# Displaying individual errors Inertia Vue - Laravel App

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

So I have a dynamic table, where you can add as many services as you want, you can select how many of them and if you want to have a discount for each service

```
<tr v-if="proceduresList.length" v-for="(procedure,index) in proceduresList" :key="procedure.id">
   <td>{{ procedure.name }}</td>
   <td>
      <input v-model="procedure.amount" type="number" step="any" class="form-control">                            
   </td>
   <td>
       <input v-model="procedure.discount" type="number" step="any" class="form-control">
   </td>
   <td class="text-center">
       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeProcedure(procedure)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I have a validation for the procedures array in my laravel backend whick, In case of errors, returns something like this

```
errors:Object
 description:"The description field is required."
 procedures.0.amount:"The procedures.0.amount field is required."
 procedures.1.discount:"The procedures.1.discount field is required."
 procedures.2.amount:"The procedures.2.amount field is required."
 procedures.2.discount:"The procedures.2.discount field is required."
 start_date:"The start date field is required."
```

What I want to do is to display the individual errors for each row, I haven't figured out how.

I tried like this

```
<input v-model="procedure.amount" type="number" step="any" class="form-control">
<span v-if="attentionForm.errors.procedures[index].amount">{{ attentionForm.errors.procedures[index].amount }}</span>
```

But when I add a service / procedure to the table, the page goes blank and in the debugger it says:

```
TypeError
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Comment: I think you need to double check maybe: `v-if="attentionForm.errors.procedures[index] && attentionForm.errors.procedures[index].amount"` because it tries directly to find the amount in error and since it is not there it crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets to access the error property:

```html
<span v-if="attentionForm.errors[`procedures.${index}.amount`]">
  {{ attentionForm.errors[`procedures.${index}.amount`] }}
</span>
```

Example here: https://youtu.be/LILSriakRZA?t=547